# Delete model and DB table in Django with migrations

Tags: django, django-models, migration, postgresql-12

I have two models: **Clause** and **Template**, they have been migrated locally, but I want to delete one of them. The question is: If I just delete it from models.py and admin.py, and run makemigration and migrate,  how can I delete and the related  DB table as well? Should I delete DB table manualy or the migrations will delete it ?

Comment: Yes, if you delete the model you will lose all associated model data.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete one or more from the models.py they will be deleted also in the DB.

The makemigration resets the DB and the migrate command will confirm it.